# Путаница с библиотеками

Tags: android, android-sdk

Хочу привести в порядок общие знания по Android, а именно:

1. Что включает в себя `Android SDK`(понимаю, что включает в себя библиотки в том числе и какие-то стандартные, но какие?)
2. `Jetpack` входит в `Android SDK`?
3. До того, как в `Jetpack` поместили библиотеки поддержки и другие они входили в `Android SDK`?

Понимаю, что вопрос возможно странный, но для меня немного непонятен этот момент. Допустим есть библиотека `Dagger` и я четко понимаю, что это сторонняя библиотека. А с библиотеками от гугла не совсем понятно, какие являются стандартными а какие нет. Просто пытаюсь разложить все по полочкам.

Comment: Поправка, dagger от гугла, но она вроде как не является стандартной

Comment: Вам сюда - https://github.com/mobile-roadmap/android-developer-roadmap

Comment: Вау, это то, что я искал, правда на мой вопрос все же не дает ответа

Comment: Если быть точным, то SDK - это пакет разработчика, а не библиотека - в него входят и стандартные библиотеки, и среда разработки, и любые программные инструменты, используемые для разработки, отладки и сборки. И тут сложно ответить что считать частью SDK, а что нет. Стандартными библиотеками следует считать предустанавливаемые на устройства (как часть ОС) и не требующие включения их в состав пользовательского приложения. Jetpack этому условию не удовлетворяет, равно как и все библиотеки добавляемые к проекту дополнительно (блок `dependencies` в `build.gradle` стандартного проекта AS).